# Magento 2: Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component on cart page

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am using Magento 2.3.4, I am getting this error on my cart page and also not showing the tax and discount sidebar on the cart page, this error is coming on console.

After debugging I came to know that it is conflicting with a third party extension - **Multisafepay**, the payment gateway when disabling this module the cart page is working fine.[image]

I am not able to disable the `magento_giftmessage` module as many other modules are dependant on it.